# Is the grenade launcher indirect-capable or not?

Tags: only-war

The flavor text for the grenade launcher in Only War on page 182 specifically calls out:

> These shots can be arced high into the air as suppressive fire at unseen targets as well as being used directly against foes.

The weapon itself doesn't have the "indirect" trait, so is this just flavor text that has no actual rules bearing? Or is the weapon allowed to be fired indirectly (as many real world grenade launchers are) so long as one follows the same rules for indirect weapons fire, i.e. a spotter or auspex is required and if missed you have some *x* value for shot deviation?

Or is there some "suppressing" trait that I am missing? There seems to be some vague meaning behind this.

Answer (score 1):

## This is flavour

Unless something is specifically explained in the rules then it is not in the rules, as the weapon lacks the "indirect" trait this is likely just flavour fluff, although there's nothing preventing you from making a home rule ammending this

Comment: Can you provide support for this? Using words like “likely” and generic sentences that could be written about any RPG makes this post seem *likely* to be a guess rather than based on familiarity with Only War’s system and the relationship between its descriptions and its mechanics (which I not the same in every RPG). This post would be improved by supporting it with direct citations that Only War works the way you’re saying it does, or extended discussion from experience why it does.

Comment: For example, you could discuss how the system models suppressing fire (or doesn’t), and how that sheds light on the description of the grenade launcher and supports this conclusion. There are other ways to support the answer; that’s just one possible approach.